# highcharts not displaying line when last point is before current x Axis minimum and next point is after current X Axis maximum

Tags: javascript, jquery, configuration, highcharts

Here is my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Y5FY9/

I have a chart configured thus:

```
   chart: {
    marginBottom: 80,
    reflow: false,
    spacingLeft: 30,
    marginRight: 20,
    style: {
        position: 'absolute'
    },
    borderColor: '#000000',
    borderRadius: 20,
    borderWidth: 1
},
```

Using the Master-Detail setup if the starting configuration is so that the last point of a line graph falls off the current X Axis viewing range then no line is displayed, as shown in the above JSFiddle example link.

Similarly if you zoom the Master graph (bottom one) so that the last point is off to the left and the next point is off to the right then no line is displayed.

How do I configure Highcharts to display the line even if no points fall within the current X Axis range so that at least you can see something?

Users aren't always aware that they haven't selected any points butthe plot suddenly disappears as far as users are concerned.

I'm hoping this is just a configuration settings somewhere but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

In that lines you are filtering data:

```
                jQuery.each(this.series[0].data, function(i, point) {
                    if (point.x > min && point.x < max) {
                        detailData.push({
                            x: point.x,
                            y: point.y
                        });
                    }
                });
```

As you can see, when points are outside the range, nothing is added. You can add at least two points to display line on a chart.